# Combining Ruby on Rails, jQuery, AJAX, and the Embedly API

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, embed

I'm having trouble understanding how to navigate the combination of all of these languages/services: Ruby on Rails, jQuery, AJAX, and the Embedly API

Essentially what I want to build is an app that allows a user to input a video url into a text field, and then use the embedly-jQuery api to retrieve the thumbnail and return it with ajax. Then when the user clicks the thumbnail, the thumbnail hides and the embedded video appears.

Here's the code in my application.js file. From what I understand, this code embeds the video into the `#video_div` element. Also, I'm unsure whether I can use the `@video.video_url` variable in my application.js file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$.embedly('#{@video.video_url}',
           {maxWidth: 600,
               elems: $('#video_div'),
             success: function(oembed, dict){
                        alert(oembed.title);
                      });
      });
```

Here's my `new` view corresponding to the new action. It includes the form that the user submits the link to, as well as the div with id `video_id` where the video should be embedded.

```
<%= form_for(@video) do |f| %>
  <% if @video.errors.any? %>
    <div id="errorExplanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@video.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this video from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @video.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :video_url %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :video_url %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<div id="video_div"></div>
```

However, the video is not embedded. Why is this? Do I need to add something like `format.js` to my create method in my video controller and then add a `create.js.erb` file? If so, what should go into this file? Let me know if I should post more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't have access to @video.video_url in a javascript file. That's a client side file.

To access it like that, you'll need to use the rails erb (or haml etc) templating engine, which operates server side.

Options:

1. Move all the javascript code into the .erb file to use #{@video.video_url} directly
2. Pass the information about the video URL when you load your javascript functions

Comment: How do I pass the information about the video URl when I load my js functions? I have it stored in the db.

Comment: Oh probably a CSS selector, but what would that javascript code look like? I'd probably need to add `<%= link_to 'video', @video.video_url %>` in the `#video_div` element.

Comment: In that case, put your javascript code inside of the erb file, much easier